# CSS Menu - Drop Down not working

Tags: html, css

Hi i have a pure CSS menu but i cannot figure out how to turn it into a drop down menu. This menu below works fine as a horizontal entry but when i try to add a drop down it does not appear and is not working.

Can someone advise what i have missed to make this work ?

**css**

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    position: relative;

    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.1);

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

#container ul {
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    background: #5c6063;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#4d000000',GradientType=0 );

    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#container ul li {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #666;
    border-left: 1px solid #444;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}


#container ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 11px/41px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ddd;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 35px;

}

#container ul li:active {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}

#container ul li:first-child {
    border-left: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
    border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
}

#container ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 100px 100px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 100px 100px 0;
    border-radius: 0 100px 100px 0;
}


/*

TEST TEST TEST TEST

*/


#container ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.08);
}

#container li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#container li:hover li
{
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#container li:hover a 
{
    background: #617F8A;
}

#container li:hover li a:hover 
{
    background: #95A9B1;
}
```

**html**

```
<center>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="forgot.php">Forgotten Password</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="terms.php">Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</center>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USPy5/)

Comment: Also the `<center>` element has been deprecated under HTML5 and should no longer be used.

Comment: the html is added below the style, this is a small file which i am using php include to add the menu onto multiple pages

Answer (score 1):

```
ul
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

li ul
{
    display: none;
}

ul li a 
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #2C5463;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover 
{
    background: #617F8A;
}
li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li
{
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a 
{
    background: #617F8A;
}

li:hover li a:hover 
{
    background: #95A9B1;
}
```